# Div background image not showing in heroku. However, the logo shows

Tags: css

I tried changing the image tag, no luck with that. I reviewed other post  here and tried those solutions none work. I also use amazon cloudfront.

```
<div id="signup" class="container-fluid">
</div>

#signup{
text-align: center;
background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.3), rgba(0,0,0,0.4)),
url("zoom1028.jpg");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On chrome right click inspect, the developers tools should show up, now click on the tab network, and see if there is any 404 error, maybe the image url isn't pointing were it should.

Check this example i built with your code:

https://jsfiddle.net/opqtncms/1/

```
<div id="signup" class="container-fluid">
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
</div>


#signup {
  text-align: center;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)), url("https://www.google.com.mx/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png");
}
```

Best regards!.

Comment: I found a solution after using your method to discover the issue. Image path was point somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the # selector because "signup" is an id.

```
#signup{
...
}
```

Comment: The selector is on, I must have deleted it in my posting.

Comment: @user3905353 Then update your question, otherwise you'll end up with more "its a typo" responses.

Answer (score 0):

First set the `fallback background-image` then apply the `gradient` on the image.

```
#signup{
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url("zoom1028.jpg"); # fallback
  background-image: url("zoom1028.jpg"), linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.3), rgba(0,0,0,0.4));
```

}

Hope this would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I used sass Image specific helper:
background-image: image-url("photo.jpg") and it worked. According to sass instructions here https://github.com/rails/sass-rails.